# python and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

I have a little problem with local variables and python (2.7).

I have a little code :

```
def foo(a):
    def bar():
        print a
    return bar()

>>>foo(5)
5
```

Well, it's working, but if want to modify a , like this :

```
def foo(a):
    def bar():
        a -= 1
    return bar()
>>>foo(5) 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

So I must affect 'a' to another variable.

But I don't understand this comportment.
Is it because when there is an assignment, python looks in the locals() variables and doesn't find it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `bar()` inside of `bar()` in your second example? It must stop with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` as soon as you're past the line with the assignment.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value 
| http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python

Comment: In your second example you are returning bar() in bar(), is that what you want or an indent/copy error? Because you don't have it in your first example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've found something that used to be an issue in Python! The short answer is that you can't do this in Python 2.x (though you can [simulate](http://davidchambersdesign.com/simulating-nonlocal-in-python-2.x/)) it, but you can in 3.x using the `nonlocal` keyword.

See [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/):

> Before version 2.1, Python's treatment of scopes resembled that of
>   standard C: within a file there were only two levels of scope, global
>   and local. In C, this is a natural consequence of the fact that
>   function definitions cannot be nested. But in Python, though functions
>   are usually defined at the top level, a function definition can be
>   executed anywhere. This gave Python the syntactic appearance of nested
>   scoping without the semantics, and yielded inconsistencies that were
>   surprising to some programmers -- for example, a recursive function
>   that worked at the top level would cease to work when moved inside
>   another function, because the recursive function's own name would no
>   longer be visible in its body's scope. This violates the intuition
>   that a function should behave consistently when placed in different
>   contexts. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> def enclosing_function():
>     def factorial(n):
>         if n < 2:
>             return 1
>         return n * factorial(n - 1)  # fails with NameError
>     print factorial(5)
> ```
>
> Python 2.1 moved closer to static nested scoping by making visible the
>   names bound in all enclosing scopes (see PEP 227). This change makes
>   the above code example work as expected. However, because any
>   assignment to a name implicitly declares that name to be local, it is
>   impossible to rebind a name in an outer scope (except when a global
>   declaration forces the name to be global). Thus, the following code,
>   intended to display a number that can be incremented and decremented
>   by clicking buttons, doesn't work as someone familiar with lexical
>   scoping might expect:
>
> ```
> def make_scoreboard(frame, score=0):
>     label = Label(frame)
>     label.pack()
>     for i in [-10, -1, 1, 10]:
>         def increment(step=i):
>             score = score + step  # fails with UnboundLocalError
>             label['text'] = score
>         button = Button(frame, text='%+d' % i, command=increment)
>         button.pack()
>     return label
> ```
>
> Python syntax doesn't provide a way to indicate that the name score
>   mentioned in increment refers to the variable score bound in
>   make_scoreboard, not a local variable in increment. Users and
>   developers of Python have expressed an interest in removing this
>   limitation so that Python can have the full flexibility of the
>   Algol-style scoping model that is now standard in many programming
>   languages, including JavaScript, Perl, Ruby, Scheme, Smalltalk, C with
>   GNU extensions, and C# 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

The reason given by Constantinius is correct. Another way of dealing with it (without using global variables) would be

```
def foo(a):
    def bar(a):
        a -= 1
        return a
    return bar(a)
>>> print foo(5) 
4
```